# How create a Actionbarcompact Settings?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am developing an application using the Action Bar Compact. 
Right now I'm trying to set the Activity Application Preferences. 
As Java does not have multiple inheritance can not inherit both ActionBarCompact and Preference Activity.

I need a way to use the two classes at a time, so you can use the Action-bar to navigate and to use Preference Activity activity as Preferences.

PS: My apologies if the question is not clear, my English is not quite good.